# Replace defalut woocommerce category view by using plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Default whole woocommerce category content and replace it with custom value or replace woocoomerce category page with another just by calling in plugin.

based on [this link](https://storecustomizer.com/woocommerce-shop-page-hooks-visual-guide/) it seems there is no action for whole shop category page content.

its important to doing this with custom plugin and not any changes on template.

Answer (score 0):

i found a simple answer.
use JS to hide shop loop divs and add my plugin resluts to `woocommerce_before_shop_loop`.

Attention: this is not a really good solution.